# Qt: How to get mounted drives

Tags: qt, user-interface, model-view-controller, filesystems, drives

I'm writing a Qt GUI app.

I'm using `QFileSystemModel` for local files, and I just learned that it doesn't work with mounted drives.

Yes, I can get all currently mounted drives by calling

```
view->setRootIndex(fileSystemModel->setRootPath(""));
```

But the problem is that the view connected to this model is not updated when drives get mounted or unmounted.

One of the things I can do is call `QDir::drives()` every second or so to get the list of currently mounted drives. But I don't like this idea. Maybe you know a better one?

Comment: Is the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5043096/104370 any use?

Comment: not sure but might be QFileSystemWatcher can help ? if you can watch /mnt or som eother location where device is mounted?