# How to detect a Windows USB storage with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb

Hello this is my first post on stackoverflow and I need help to detect only one usb slot.

Currently I am working with qt c++ on displaying folders and files in a "QTreeWidgetItem".
For now, I managed to recover files from an existing folder with:
QDir folder;
folder.entryInfoList()

Now, I’d like to do the same with a usb device, in the following order:

- Detection usb
- Recovery usb path
- Giving usb path to QTreeWidget

The problem is, I don’t know how to detect a usb notification.
I found an old post but the code is complicated and I think a simpler solution exists:
[Detecting USB notification in Qt on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043096/detecting-usb-notification-in-qt-on-windows)

The first solution found is the use of "QStorageInfo" with the method mountedVolumes() to recover usb folder path :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#mountedVolumes

The second solution found is the use of "QFileSystemWatcher" on a fixed folder type (D:/). However Windows dynamically assigns drive letters for USB drives and if the letter changes, this no longer works.

For the moment, I was thinking of a "barbaric" solution, using "QFileSystemWatcher::addPath" on all letters of the alphabet and retrieve the signal of a change. Normally, as I use only one usb port, this technique is supposed to return me a file path.

I would like to have opinions on the solutions adopted and a simple solution to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use QIODevice for that case. I use this for my Arduino on USB-Port.

Comment: How to initialise?

Comment: QIODevice is an abstract class. Can you provide more information about how you use it ?